# Modify a column in Python such that the numbering is continuous

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset given as such:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd


#Create dataset
data = {'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
        'Run_time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Married': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
        'Self_Employed': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
        'LoanAmount': [123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,96,15,85,36,58,89],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("df = \n", df)
```

The dataset looks as such:

[image]

Here, in the 'Run_time' column, the numbering starts at different index values.

I wish to ensure that the 'Run_time' column starts from 1 only.

The dataset needs to look as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how to modify this column in Python such that the numbering is continuous?

Comment: doesn't it just replicate the index (+1) then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


#Create dataset
data = {'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
        'Run_time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Married': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No'],
        'Self_Employed': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'],
        'LoanAmount': [123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,96,15,85,36,58,89],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# print("df = \n", df)
df.Run_time = df.index+1
df
```

Comment: `df['Run_time'] = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)` is a safer choice, it will work independently of the index.

Comment: Absolutely @mozway. This approach is better, I agree.